# Get current page / view name in ionic 2 rc0

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to handle navigation based on the current view name.

So when the user is on any other view I want the back button to take the user to the home page. And if the user in on the home page i want to prompt for exit.

Pretty standard stuff.

I am using the tabs template, I have more pages that the out of the box tabs template.

Currently I am doing the following in my **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';


@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{
         //how do i handle back button
       },600)
    });
 }



}
```

Comment: Have you tried navController.getActive()?

Comment: yes, I tried it..when I inject the NavController into the constructor of the app.component.ts i get an exception EXCEPTION: No provider for t!

Comment: Can't inject to app cause no view exist...so you can't do it from app ts...

Comment: yup but Nav can be injected so it worki by injecting nav:Nav

Comment: @krv can place your answer so every one can make use of it

Answer (score 1):

Another work around is to hook into the `platform.url()` and then base the conditional on the last segment of the url

```
this.platform.url().split("/").pop() != 'home'
```